# Javascript Drag and drop change div dragDrop

Tags: javascript

How can drag and drop to replace the elements I dragstart, drop all implemented.only I can't replace the div. the function that can be replaced can be replaced . Only javascript.please help me.

```js
const dragAndDrop = () => {
    const zono1 = document.querySelector('.zono-1');
    const zono2 = document.querySelector('.zono-2');
    const zono3 = document.querySelector('.zono-3');
    const zono4 = document.querySelector('.zono-4');
    const zono5 = document.querySelector('.zono-5');
    const zono6 = document.querySelector('.zono-6');
    const zono7 = document.querySelector('.zono-5');
    const zono8 = document.querySelector('.zono-6');
    const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.js-cell')
    const dragStart = function () {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.classList.add('hide');
        }, 0)
    };
    const dragEnd = function () {
        this.classList.remove('hide');
    };

    const dragOver = function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    };
    const dragEnter = function () {
        console.log('enter')
    };
    const dragLeave = function () {
        console.log('leave')
    };
    const dragDrop = function () {

        //  ?????????????????????????????????

    };

    cells.forEach((cell) => {
        console.log(cell);
        cell.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
        cell.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
        cell.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
        cell.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);

    });

    zono1.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);//all Element zono
    zono1.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
}
dragAndDrop()
```

```html
<div class="zono-1 js-cell"  draggable="true" >
  <h3 id="title">javacript</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-2 js-cell"   draggable="true">
  <h3 id="title">Ask a public question</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-3 js-cell" draggable="true">
  <h3 id="title">Step to Web</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-4 js-cell"  draggable="true">
  <h3 id="title">Игровая консоль Microsoft Xbox ONE Black 500 Gb</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-5 js-cell"  draggable="true">
  <h3 id="title">vue</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-6 js-cell"  draggable="true">
  <h3 id="title">СВАРОГ REAL SMART ARC 160 (Z28103)</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-7 js-cell"  draggable="true">
  <h3 id="title">СВАРОГ REAL MIG 200 (N24002N) BLACK (МАСКА+КРАГИ)</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-8 js-cell"  draggable="true">
  <h3 id="title">TRITON ALUTIG 200P AC/DC</h3>  
</div>
```

How can Drag and drop replace the elements I dragstart, drop all implemented.only I can't replace the div. the function that can be replaced can be replaced . Only javascript.please help me.

Comment: @DoanVanThang can replace the elements there

Comment: Can you write more specific? From where to where?

Comment: @DoanVanThang if you drop the item, it is swapped

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, you can check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to get `from` element with `dragstart` and `to` element with `event.target` then clone those nodes, use `replaceChild` twice to replace them. Remember to attach events again because `cloneNode` [does not copy event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)

```js
var from;

const dragAndDrop = () => {
const zono1 = document.querySelector('.zono-1');
const zono2 = document.querySelector('.zono-2');
const zono3 = document.querySelector('.zono-3');
const zono4 = document.querySelector('.zono-4');
const zono5 = document.querySelector('.zono-5');
const zono6 = document.querySelector('.zono-6');
const zono7 = document.querySelector('.zono-5');
const zono8 = document.querySelector('.zono-6');
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('.js-cell')
const dragStart = function (event) {
    from = event.target;
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.classList.add('hide');
    }, 0)
};
const dragEnd = function () {
    this.classList.remove('hide');
};

const dragOver = function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
};
const dragEnter = function () {
    // console.log('enter')
};
const dragLeave = function () {
    // console.log('leave')
};
const dragDrop = function (event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // prevent bubbling of events.
    let to = event.target;
    if (to.nodeName == "H3")
        to = to.parentNode;
    if (from == to) // check if drag to itself
        return false;
    let CopyTo = to.cloneNode(true);
    let CopyFrom = from.cloneNode(true);
    to.parentNode.replaceChild(CopyFrom, to);
    from.parentNode.replaceChild(CopyTo, from);
    dragAndDrop();
};

cells.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
    cell.addEventListener('dragend', dragEnd);
    cell.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
    cell.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
    cell.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
    cell.addEventListener('drop', dragDrop);
});
}
dragAndDrop()
```

```html
<div class="zono-1 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">javacript</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-2 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">Ask a public question</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-3 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">Step to Web</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-4 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">Игровая консоль Microsoft Xbox ONE Black 500 Gb</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-5 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">vue</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-6 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">СВАРОГ REAL SMART ARC 160 (Z28103)</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-7 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">СВАРОГ REAL MIG 200 (N24002N) BLACK (МАСКА+КРАГИ)</h3>
</div>

<div class="zono-8 js-cell" draggable="true">
    <h3 id="title">TRITON ALUTIG 200P AC/DC</h3>
</div>
```